# "Only the good die young." Negative or Positive?

Tags: expressions, expression-choice

I've heard this expression before. I can't tell if its used as a positive one or a negative one? When is it appropriate to use this expression?

Is it implying that people that live to be an old age are "bad"?

Is it something you say to someone's surviving friends and family that has passed at a young age?

Comment: The "standard" expression is [*“**The good die young**”*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%E2%80%9Cthe+good+die+young%E2%80%9D&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl). I suspect many of those who preface it with ***only*** don't really realise that *in principle* they're changing the meaning somewhat.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Actually, the version with *only* is probably 'standard' now, thanks to the [Billy Joel song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zhjNm20XbXw)!

Comment: @StoneyB: I can't see much support for than [in NGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+good+die+young%2Conly+the+good+die+young&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20good%20die%20young%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Conly%20the%20good%20die%20young%3B%2Cc0), but of course that's only *written* instances. Anyway, strictly speaking I'd say the "original" is [*"Whom the gods love die young"*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trophonius), and I certainly don't think *that* would be "improved" by adding ***only***.

Comment: It is probably **NOT** appropriate to use the phrase when talking to the relative/friend of someone recently deceased.  There may be cases where it's appropriate, but you'd have to know the situation.

Comment: @Hot Licks: Absolutely. People come out with all sorts of drivel because they don't know what to say in such circumstances, but it's about as "comforting" as being told *"At least s/he had a good innings"* when a parent dies.

Comment: @FumbleFingers My father died last year, three months before he was due to be 100. From the age of about 90 he would give his age as something or other 'not out'. But like many a batsman at the crease he failed at the dreadful barrier of 99 and an easy-looking full toss from the bowler.

Comment: In the final analysis, whether OP's text is appropriate in genuine "condolences" contexts is entirely a matter of opinion and circumstance. If there's an "Etiquette" SE site it belongs there, but from the ELU perspective I think it's Off Topic (Primarily Opinion-based), so I'm closevoting accordingly.

Comment: Yahoo! @FumbleFingers, Oh, drat! Talk about riding an emotional rollercoaster. Hey! I am Halfling here, wending my way among giants, toss me a crumb!

Comment: @Little Eva: Crumb? Have the whole loaf! Your powers of expression are obviously as good as anyone here, and your answer (which I've only just read and upvoted) seems to sum up everything relevant to the question, Off Topic or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, either as "Whom the gods love die young," *or* "Only the good die young," the statement is *poetic*, reverberating with multiple meanings. The [ambiguity](http://www.iasj.net/iasj?func=fulltext&aId=43358) which gives rise to your question is an essential and desirable component of poetry, where *what it **means*** is often less important to the poet than *how it **feels***. Take care when making ambiguous statements at sensitive social situations. Those who know you well will likely interpret such speech as *benediction*. Those who don't know you quite as well ... ?

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, when "only the good die young" is used, it's not really dealing with the alternative "only the bad die old". The phrase is more referring to the person that has passed-- commenting on their good nature and youth.

Referring to etiquette, this isn't something that would be used to comfort friends and family of a young death as it can seem quite unfeeling. Most of the times I've heard it used, it's a retrospective statement, after friends/others (generally not family) have had time to accept the death, and now they're looking back, commenting on the person.

Answer (score 0):

As used in the Billy Joel song, it laments the loss of someone at a young age and uses that to promote being 'not so good', or a bit rebellious.  Not something to say to family of a lost one.

Answer (score 0):

Agreeing with the idea that the phrase is "reverberating with multiple meanings", it seem to me that the poetic ambiguity is increased by the addition of 'only'.  Only the good die young encourages me to think that *anyone* who dies young is, and can only be, good.

Answer (score 0):

Billy Joel's lyric seems to be saying that you can only be good if you die young (because all of us, with age, sin).